# ¿Por qué FGETS da error cuando lo inserto en un BUCLE como variable, pero no cuando lo inserto directamente como método?

Tags: php, fgets

Aqui funciona:

```
$ABRIR = fopen( "fichero.html", 'r' );

while (!feof($ABRIR)) {
  echo fgets( $ABRIR );
}
```

**Pero aqui falla**, apesar de que estoy haciendo lo mismo que arriba, sólo que metiendo el método FGETS en una variable:

```
$ABRIR = fopen( "fichero.html", 'r' );

$LEER = fgets( $ABRIR );

while (!feof($ABRIR)) {
  echo $LEER;
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres que falla? ¿El problema es que no lee el archivo completo?

Comment: El navegador muestra un mensaje de error......Pero cuando pongo el metodo directamente, es decir, sin que la variable lo contenga, funciona!

Comment: No da error. Muestra el bucle infinitamente, lo que hace que el navegador: crash!

Answer (score 0):

El error que se produce en el segundo caso, se debe a que [`fgets`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php) lee la primer línea del archivo, pero el puntero **no llega al `final del archivo (EOF)`**.

> La lectura termina cuando se han leído length - 1 bytes, **o una nueva línea (la cual está incluida en el valor de retorno)**, o un EOF (lo que suceda primero).

Lo que provoca que `!feof($ABRIR)` se igual a `true`. Si siempre es verdadero (*porque nunca mas se le pide que se mueva el puntero*) tenemos que `while (!feof($ABRIR))`  **realizara un bucle infinito**.

Finalmente `PHP` detiene la ejecución ya sea por [`máximo de tiempo de ejecución`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) o alguna otra regla de limites.

#### Conclusión:

El error se da por asumir que  `fgets( $ABRIR );`  lee la totalidad del archivo y sitúa el puntero al final del mismo (`EOF`) con solo llamarlo una vez.

Comment: ¿Existe otra forma de hacer que gfets traiga todo el contenido del archivo, o mejor, que traiga una linea determinada, digamos la linea 5?